# Hover effect for non-square, transparent icon image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

as you will see at jsfiddle, even though I dont enter inside image, it starts to hover effect. I think, it sees my image as square. How can I solve this ?

not: there is a gift icon at app.

```
<img id="image" src="http://i.hizliresim.com/kvAl3v.png" ></img>

img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 black)
              drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 black);
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 black) 
      drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 black);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hLtbgzg6/

Comment: You don't. An image is a block element. What you're looking for is an .svg/vector.

Comment: what the hell. i just start web-design and got stuck. this seemed so easy

Comment: shall i download this image as svg ?

Comment: Well, no. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics There's no easy elegant solution for this; it can be done using imagemaps and javascript, but again, not elegant.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the img element will always be seen as a block by the browsers when processing your hover CSS.

But do you really need to have this exact? If you really really do, than you might want to combine http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp area with on mouse over events, which would assign a new class (e.g. `hovered`) to your image. Then add the filter css to that class instead.

```
img.hovered {
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 black)
drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 black);
filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 black) 
drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 black);
}
```

Note that you don't need the closing tag `<\img>` for img elements, this is invalid HTML.

Comment: I started to try it with javascript with mousemove event as there is 4 square